# Float dash to dock

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments, ubuntu-dock, dock, dash-to-dock

I use dash to dock instead of ubuntu dock. Is there a way to keep dash to dock floating? Like the dock below?

My dash to dock:
[image]

The kind of dock that I want:
[image]

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: @heynnema Second one has space from bottom.

Comment: That's it? The space? The bottom one is a Mac. You're running Linux. Maybe find a Mac theme and it'll float the dock... see https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/

Comment: @heynnema Are themes change appearance of dash to dock? I think they change ubuntu dock appearance not external ones. And also I like my theme and don't want to change it. If I can do it with dash to dock settings or dconf, it will be great.

Comment: @RezaHosseinzadeh in that case you need to edit the theme you want to stick to.

Comment: @UnKNOWn Can you give me a tutorial link?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @UnKNOWn I use the latest version. Ububtu 21.04.

Comment: Ok, let me go through it and give you the steps..

Comment: stylesheet.css file of the extension. line 41 to 44 Edited Content `#dashtodockContainer.dashtodock.bottom #dash {
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    margin: 20px;
}` Drawback.. "use built in theme" under Appearance Tab of Extension's Settings must be on. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahn1D.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM8xl.png